# sendAction() method. Access to an actions in the controller

Tags: ember.js

I need to access to a method defined inside actions in my HomeController but I keep getting an undefined.
I discover that there is this sendAction() method made for this but after reading the documentation, the github issues and some (there are just a few) stackoverflow related topic, I give up and decided for a dirty way. 
But still, i would understand would be the right way to use it.
Here the code:

```
    ArtRank.HomeController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    photoIndex: 0,

    actions: {
        nextPhoto: function() {    
            this.set('photoIndex', this.get('photoIndex') + 1);
            var items;

        },
        prevPhoto: function() {
            this.set('photoIndex', this.get('photoIndex') - 1);
        }
    },

    init: function() {
        var controller = this;
        this.set('photoTimer', setInterval(function(){
            Ember.run(function() {
                controller.nextPhoto();
            });
        }, 3000));
    }

});
```

I need to access to a nextPhoto() in my init function. But nextPhoto() is inside actions so it give me an undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `controller.send(actionName, args ...)`.

Observation: I don't know if is possible to trigger an action inside of `init` method, so I used `startTimer: function(){}.on('init')`, this method will be triggered after the object creation, and setup.

```
ArtRank.HomeController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    photoIndex: 0,

    actions: {
        nextPhoto: function() {    
            this.set('photoIndex', this.get('photoIndex') + 1);
            var items;

        },
        prevPhoto: function() {
            this.set('photoIndex', this.get('photoIndex') - 1);
        }
    },

    startTimer: function() {
        var controller = this;
        this.set('photoTimer', setInterval(function(){
            Ember.run(function() {
                controller.send('nextPhoto');
            });
        }, 3000));
    }.on('init')
});
```

Comment: Cool thanks, it works! So i did it right but doesn't work in init, interesting.